# Merge two tables in one output

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these two different tables. The column 'timelistenr' are the same in both but the rest of the columns are different. I want to print them both in one single table but I don't know the easiest way to do it?

```
SELECT * FROM timelistelinje WHERE timelistenr > 7;

SELECT * FROM timeliste WHERE timelistenr > 7;
```

timelistelinje contains: timelistenr | linjenr | startdato  | starttid | sluttid  | pause |  beskrivelse

timeliste contains: timelistenr |  status  |   levert   |  utbetalt  |    beskrivelse

(NB 'beskrivelse' contains different values.)

Comment: Add some sample data for both tables, and the combined result. Formatted text, not images please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Liam said, or alternatively:

```
SELECT * FROM timeliste l, timelistelinje ln
WHERE l.timelistenr = ln.timelistenr AND ln.timelistenr > 7
```

Comment: This is going to be considerably less efficient than an inner join. This produces a Cartesian product of the two tables and then filters them.

Comment: @Liam Agreed, in fact I would use inner joins myself. I suggested this method because he asked for the 'easiest' way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Use an [INNER JOIN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190014(v=sql.105).aspx)

> An inner join is a join in which the values in the columns being
>   joined are compared using a comparison operator.

```
SELECT * FROM timelistelinje as a
INNER JOIN
timeliste as b
ON a.timelistenr  = b.timelistenr 
 WHERE a.timelistenr > 7;
```

Comment: I get this error:  column reference "timelistenr" is ambiguous

Comment: Needed to specify the table in WHERE clause

Answer (score 1):

You can Use Join Query For This Process

```
Select tbl_timelistelinje.*, tbl_timeliste.* from tbl_timelistelinje inner join tbl_timeliste on timeliste=timeliste where timeliste > 7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.timelistenr FROM timelistelinje t1
WHERE <condition for timelistelinje>
UNION 
SELECT t2.timelistenr FROM timeliste t2
WHERE <condition for timeliste>
```

This simply prints out the values for timelistenr of both tables applying the conditions separately. This makes no assumptions about the relationship between either table, but depending on what you need it for, this could be exactly what you're looking for.